# DAX language- Microsoft Power BI - SUMMARIZE inside SELECTCOLUMNS - simple syntax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, ssas-tabular

I have a situation below (Power BI - DAX) in which I am trying to SUMMARIZE a table called Product with a SUM aggregation to get the total cost of all products in each Category; but then I have to change the column name of one or two columns in the summarized result set.

I have written the below code to develop a calculated table:

```
ProductCategoryCostCT = SELECTCOLUMNS (

                                       SUMMARIZE(

                                                 Product,

                                                 Product[Category],

                                                 "TotalCostOfAllProductsInThisCategory", SUM(Product[ProductCost])

                                                ),

                                      "CategoryName", Product[Category],

                                      "Cost",  Product[TotalCostOfAllProductsInThisCategory]

                                     )
```

The above code throws an error. Can someone help me correct this ? This may be pedestrian to many of you!

(The source Product table has ProductCost column at the individual Product level, with Category as another column
in the same table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ProductCategoryCostCT =  SUMMARIZE(

                                    SELECTCOLUMNS(

                                                   Product,

                                                   "CategoryName", Product[Category],
                                                   "ProductCost", Product[ProductCost]

                                                 ),

                                    [CategoryName],

                                    "Cost", SUM(Product[ProductCost])

                                  )
```